# Sign a pdf using itext 7 version 8.0.X

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature, itext7

We are using iText7 version 7.X dotnet for the last few years to digitally sign PDF's.

It is working great (and still does) but iText7 released a new verison (with the somewhat confusing name version 8) which is not compatible with our code.

Cant seem to find any updated example for version 8 on how to sign a PDF.

Here is the code we are using :

```
public class PdfSigner
{
    IExternalSignature _privateSignature;
    X509Certificate[] _signChain;

    public PdfSigner(Stream privateKeyStream, string keyPassword)
    {
        var pks = new Pkcs12Store(privateKeyStream, keyPassword.ToCharArray());
        string alias = null;
        foreach (string tAlias in pks.Aliases)
        {
            if (pks.IsKeyEntry(tAlias))
            {
                alias = tAlias;
                break;
            }
        }
        var pk = pks.GetKey(alias).Key;
        var ce = pks.GetCertificateChain(alias);
        _signChain = new X509Certificate[ce.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < ce.Length; ++k)
            _signChain[k] = ce[k].Certificate;
        _privateSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-512");
    }

    public void SignPDF(Stream input, Stream output, PDFSignParameters p)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
        var signer = new iText.Signatures.PdfSigner(reader, output, properties);

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = signer.GetSignatureAppearance().SetReason(p.Reason).SetLocation(p.Location);
        if (p.Image != null)
        {                
            var img = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(new BinaryReader(p.Image.Data).ReadBytes((int)p.Image.Data.Length));
            sap.SetSignatureGraphic(img);
            sap.SetLayer2Text(string.Empty);
            sap.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(p.Image.X, p.Image.Y, img.GetWidth() / p.Image.WidthRatio, img.GetHeight() / p.Image.HeigthRatio));
            sap.SetImage(img);
        }

        signer.SignDetached(_privateSignature, _signChain, null, null, null, 0, iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
}
```

There are 2 compiler errors with the code

1.Last line of the constructor

```
_privateSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-512");
```

The error is (pk parameter)

```
cannot convert from 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter' to 'iText.Commons.Bouncycastle.Crypto.IPrivateKey'
```

2.Last line of SignPDF method

```
signer.SignDetached(_privateSignature, _signChain, null, null, null, 0, iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

The error is (_signChain parameter)

```
cannot convert from 'Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[]' to 'iText.Commons.Bouncycastle.Cert.IX509Certificate[]'
```

I can not really find any documentation on how to update the code or new relevant example of a totally new code for version 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find [signing specific](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/releases/release-itext-core-8-0-0/breaking-changes-for-itext-core-8-0-0/bouncy-castle-changes) changes attached to the [changelog](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/releases/release-itext-core-8-0-0). You can also find up to date examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures). master branch will have code compatible with the latest release, and developer branch with the latest snapshot.

Comment: @André You may want to copy the example code conversion as an answer here.

Comment: just realized you're looking for C#. Those examples can be found [here](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/).

Answer (score 2):

@andre , Thanks for your link, did not find it by keyword search on few search engines.

I had to also add another nuget package to my project named "itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter"

Here is my working code on Itext7 version 8.x :

```
public class PdfSigner
{
    IExternalSignature _privateSignature;
    IX509Certificate[] _signChain;

    public PdfSigner(Stream privateKeyStream, string keyPassword)
    {
        var pks = new Pkcs12Store(privateKeyStream, keyPassword.ToCharArray());
        string alias = null;
        foreach (string tAlias in pks.Aliases)
        {
            if (pks.IsKeyEntry(tAlias))
            {
                alias = tAlias;
                break;
            }
        }
        var pk = pks.GetKey(alias).Key;
        var ce = pks.GetCertificateChain(alias);
        _signChain = new IX509Certificate[ce.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < ce.Length; ++k)
            _signChain[k] = new X509CertificateBC(ce[k].Certificate);
        _privateSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(new PrivateKeyBC(pk), "SHA-512");
    }

    public void SignPDF(Stream input, Stream output, PDFSignParameters p)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
        var signer = new iText.Signatures.PdfSigner(reader, output, properties);

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = signer.GetSignatureAppearance().SetReason(p.Reason).SetLocation(p.Location);
        if (p.Image != null)
        {                
            var img = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(new BinaryReader(p.Image.Data).ReadBytes((int)p.Image.Data.Length));
            sap.SetSignatureGraphic(img);
            sap.SetLayer2Text(string.Empty);
            sap.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(p.Image.X, p.Image.Y, img.GetWidth() / p.Image.WidthRatio, img.GetHeight() / p.Image.HeigthRatio));
            sap.SetImage(img);
        }

        signer.SignDetached(_privateSignature, _signChain, null, null, null, 0, iText.Signatures.PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps others in the future.

Comment: here's a more [direct link](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/blob/master/itext/itext.samples/itext/samples/sandbox/signatures/SignatureExample.cs#L101) with an example on how to get `PrivateKeySignature`.